# Como mostrar un EditText en otro Activity - Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, activity, edittext, textview

Quisiera saber de que manera puedo mostrar el dato de entrada de un EditText en un TextView de otro Activity. Estoy usando Kotlin en Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar el envió de datos se realiza generalmente mediante un Bundle en el cual se pueden agregar valores y ese bundle se envía a través de un Intent. Se puede especificar el envió de cualquier tipo de elemento o array de elemento especificando el nombre:
Extraer el valor:

```
var Datos = editTextHello.text.toString();
```

Enviar valor desde HomeActivity

```
val intent = Intent(this@HomeActivity,Activity2::class.java)
intent.putExtra("Datos","Datos")
startActivity(intent)
```

Obtener valores en el otro Activity

```
val Activity2=intent.getStringExtra("Datos");
```

y luego solo extraerias el valor al TextView:

```
TextView.setText.(Datos);
```